# Unable to run .NET 6 docker 'runtimeconfig.json was not found'

Tags: .net, docker

I'm trying to set up my Docker with API in .NET 6 and Angular App which will call that APIs.

I've set my compose file like:

```
version: "3"
services: 
    proxy:
        build: 
            context: ./Proxy
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        restart: always
    client:
        build:
            context: E:\Angular\VisualOrder
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "9000:80"
    api:
        build: 
            context: E:\VisualStudio\Visual Studio 2022\VisualOrder
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "4201:80"
```

All containers goes up except of the API container which returns

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/app/'.

Failed to run as a self-contained app.

  - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/app/VisualOrder.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.

  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the '/app/VisualOrder.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

By looking for similar questions i've found that i had to set OutputType to exe and add GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles tag in csproj but nothing changed i still get the same error.

Here is my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
    <UserSecretsId>d96c762d-ae98-4b1d-a27d-af48bb400d26</UserSecretsId>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Emails\EmailNegozio.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Emails\EmailRiepilogo.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Emails\EmailNegozio.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Emails\EmailRiepilogo.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalCheckoutSdk" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalHttp" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="QRCoder" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorEngine.NetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="39.80.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And that's my Dockerfile for API

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# copy all the layers' csproj files into respective folders
COPY ["VisualOrder.csproj", "src/"]

# run restore over API project - this pulls restore over the dependent projects as well
RUN dotnet restore "src/VisualOrder.csproj"

COPY . .

# run build over the API project
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

# run publish over the API project
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN ls -l
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "VisualOrder.dll" ]
```

Comment: You have a comment in the dockerfile saying "run restore over API project - this pulls restore over the dependent projects as well". Do you have any dependent projects? If you do, you need to copy the csproj files into the image before you do `dotnet restore`.

Comment: @HansKilian i don't have any dependent project is all inside VisualOrder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that strikes me is that you copy the .csproj file into a /src/src directory which seems wrong. You're aleady in the working directory /src and then you copy the file into a src directory below that. Try changing these lines in your dockerfile

```
# copy all the layers' csproj files into respective folders
COPY ["VisualOrder.csproj", "src/"]

# run restore over API project - this pulls restore over the dependent projects as well
RUN dotnet restore "src/VisualOrder.csproj"
```

to this

```
# copy all the layers' csproj files into respective folders
COPY ["VisualOrder.csproj", "."]

# run restore over API project - this pulls restore over the dependent projects as well
RUN dotnet restore "VisualOrder.csproj"
```

Comment: By settings destination path to "." i get ` error MSB1009: Project file does not exist`.

Comment: Did you also change the restore command?

Comment: Oh i missed that part thought it was unchanged, anyway it worked in that way